# How to read Azure Table Storage data from Apache Spark running on HDInsight

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

Is it any way of doing that from a Spark application running on Azure HDInsight? We are using Scala.

Azure Blobs are supported (through WASB). I don't understand why Azure Tables aren't.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Azure Tables are not supported. Only Azure blobs support the HDFS interface required by Hadoop & Spark.

Answer (score 6):

You can actually read from Table Storage in Spark, here's a project done by a Microsoft guy doing just that:

> https://github.com/mooso/azure-tables-hadoop

You probably won't need all the Hive stuff, just the classes at root level:

- AzureTableConfiguration.java
- AzureTableInputFormat.java
- AzureTableInputSplit.java
- AzureTablePartitioner.java
- AzureTableRecordReader.java
- BaseAzureTablePartitioner.java
- DefaultTablePartitioner.java
- PartitionInputSplit.java
- WritableEntity.java

You can read with something like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(getTableConfig(tableName,account,key),
                                                classOf[AzureTableInputFormat],
                                                classOf[Text],
                                                classOf[WritableEntity])

def getTableConfig(tableName : String, account : String, key : String): Configuration = {
    val configuration = new Configuration()
    configuration.set("azure.table.name", tableName)
    configuration.set("azure.table.account.uri", account)
    configuration.set("azure.table.storage.key", key)
    configuration
  }
```

You will have to write a decoding function to transform your WritableEntity to the Class you want.

It worked for me!